# A set operation involving the intersection of two complements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm having trouble with this question. I know that
$A\ast B=(E-A)\cap (E-B)$ is also equal to $E-(A \cup B)$ but I can't make sense of the operation described in the question and I don't know how to use it to isolate the sets required.

The question reads:

> Let $E$ be a set, with subsets $A\subset E$  and $B\subset E$, and let $\ast $ be the operation $A\ast B=(E-A)\cap (E-B)$, where $E-A$ is the set of elements in $E$ that are not in $A$. Express the sets
>
> a. $A \cup B$
>
> b. $A \cap B$
>
> c. $E-A$
>
> in terms of $A,B, \ast$."

Comment: I will never understand why so many users on this site downvote posts. As if you've never had a question. Don't just downvote the post; tell me what's wrong with it so I can fix it please!

Comment: I did not down vote, but note that: right now, your first paragraph has a dangling sentence and it's rather unparsable until one realizes the second paragraph doesn't belong where it is, but rather somewhere after the question.  It would also help if you highlight what you are quoting (the question) separately from what you are commenting yourself, e.g., by using indentation `>`

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for commenting. I edited the question some, and moved the second paragraph up. I also put the actual question in quotation marks.

Comment: Was that really how it was phrased? That second paragraph is completely out of place, in between a declaration that the assigned items will follow and the actual assigned items. Also: quotation marks are easy to miss. That’s why I explicitly suggested indentation. I’ve edited it for you.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin It is how the question was phrased. I just added the description of what $E-A$ was because I know some people use the notation $E/A$.

Comment: So then, **no**, the question was not phrased as you put it, since it originally did not have the description of $E-A$ in the middle of the question, as by your admission now that was something you *added*. Really, is it so hard to see that you called yourself out for a lie in your first sentence with your second sentence?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The description of that was supposed to add clarity. Why does it matter so much? Are we seriously about to be this scrupulous about that? It was a lie, but it changes virtually nothing about the question. Why is this even worth going into detail about?

Comment: You wondered why you got downvoted; part of the reason might have been that the way you put in your “clarification” made the question hard to read, badly phrased, and poorly constructed. It made it harder to read. Thus, you were requiring more work from others, because you were careless in writing your question. As to why does it matter if you lie and try to blame others, unnamed and unknown, for your own errors and mistakes? Because it makes you dishonest. I would definitely ask: why be like that? Why be purposefully dishonest just to avoid responsibility, while whining about downvotes?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin It's not that even that deep. My intention wasn't even dishonesty. I didn't think that me trying to clarify would even be that big of a deal. I'm not blaming others either. You're making it sound as if I lied about murdering someone. It's really not that serious and I'm definitely not a dishonest person. The fact that this has to even go this far is astonishing. I'm a 20 year old man. You don't need to lecture me on honesty or anything like that. I admit my mistake. Yes, I lied. My mistake. I wasn't trying to beguile you or anything. I wasn't "purposefully being dishonest."

Answer (score 2):

Once you notice that you can express complements using $*$ (i.e., part (c) of the exercise), namely as $A*A$, the rest should fall into place. You already know how to express $E-(A\cup B)$, so with the ability to express complements you can express $A\cup B$. That, with complements and De Morgan's Law, will give you $A\cap B$ as well.